# Error in as.numeric(as.character) : cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

I am currently trying to manipulate a dataset of baseball data (i.e performing mathematical operations on the data), but unfortunately much of the quantitative data was in factor form when I downloaded it in CSV format. When I looked at the dataframe in the variable viewer in RStudio and hovered over the column name, it said it was a "factor with 1 levels", and so in order to coerce it into a numeric type, I used the following code:

`data[,"HRs"] <- sapply(data[,"HRs"],function(x) as.numeric(as.character))`

However, this code resulted in the following error message: `Error in as.numeric(as.character) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'double'.`

As a novice with r, I have no clue how to fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `data[,"HRs"] <- sapply(data[,"HRs"],function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`? The variable is missing.

Comment: Please show a smalll reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: You probably should try to fix your code that reads in the data, instead of coercing to numeric afterwards.

Comment: If your `data` is a frame, then you don't need `sapply` here, just `data[,"HRs"] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,"HRs"]))`.